# How do we reconcile between genesis and Science about livestock that created after bird

Tags: history, torah-study, food

How do we reconcile between genesis and science , I mean those which said livestock created after bird and fish , just completely and blatantly against science , this alone could knock down Christianity and Judaism because first science mistake is irrefutable because god suppose to know that and Christian couldn’t just defend New Testament but old testaments too, and there are many contradictions and any historical mistake that need to be tackle, but how this Christian people and researcher only care about NT and keep being calm even those confusing stuff are still there?

Comment: Regarding questions/comments on Christianity: that's off-topic here, but you might ask at https://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a Jewish site, btw.

Comment: let's keep questions judaism focused, we couldn't care less what christians think. we're a judaism site

Answer (score 0):

[The open text of] Genesis does seem to contradict science. However, it might be a parable (Rambam). The difficulty is thereby removed.

[1] Also, see Rabbi Slifkin's book called the challenge of creation

Comment: The Rambam's works are vast. Can you narrow it down?

Comment: The difficulty is only removed if you explain why the parable requires birds to be created first.